# jQuery Checkbox issues

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to make a jQuery function which selects all the checkboxes that are attached to it. This is the code that I have been working on. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id=checkboxes>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"> Select / Deselect All<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Eggs<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Bread<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Jam<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Tea<br>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">                
         function toggleChecked(status)
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#checkall").click(function(){
            var status = $(this).attr('checked');
            $('.checkbox').attr('checked',status);
            });
            });
</script>
```

P.S: I found this code on the net. Seemed to be working for everyone else.

Comment: You can't just grab code off the net and expect it to work with your html. That JS references elements that don't exist in your html: you don't have an element with id `"checkall"` or element(s) with the class `"checkbox"`.

Comment: I didn't merge it with my code. It's all the same code that was broken into different modules. I just arranged them together.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NXEKb/2/).It is working fine here.

Comment: Yes. It's working fine on JSFiddle. But when I copy it into my HTML and run it on Chrome, it suddenly stops working. :S

Comment: Did you use the html which is in JSFiddle? and is it says any error in chrome?

Comment: Worked! :D turns out I needed to put in <script> tags once more. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of problems. You're trying to set the checkboxes based on a class selector, but none of the checkboxes have the class. Also, the document.ready function is inside your event handler, should be the other way around...
Use the `prop()` method instead of `attr()`. And attach the event properly, something like:

```
<div id=checkboxes>
<input id="checkall" type="checkbox"> Select / Deselect All<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Eggs<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Butter<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Milk<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Bread<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Jam<br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />Tea<br>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">                

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#checkall").on("click", function(){
             var status = $(this).is(":checked");
             $('.checkbox').prop('checked', status);
         });
     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u r missing the braces while calling function...

```
 function toggleChecked(status)
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkall").click(function(){
        var status = $(this).attr('checked');
        $('.checkbox').attr('checked',status);
        });
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onclick` and make it `onchange`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id=checkboxes>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> Select / Deselect All<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Eggs<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Bread<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Jam<br>
<input type="checkbox" />Tea<br>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">                
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#checkall").click(function(){
                var status = $(this).attr('checked');
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',status);
              });
            });
</script>
```

This is binding the click event handler to the `#checkall` element on "load" which is what you want and taking the javascript onclick() method off of the element. Also you needed to add and ID to your Select all element for the selector to work.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

Change this

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason attribute value `"true"` and boolean `true` are different for a checkbox. Similarly `"false"` and boolean `false` are different.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/62w26/2/) which describes that, try changing boolean `false` to `"false"` and you will understand.

In your question, make sure you are receiving a boolean value in a status variable.